# Can morality based in pragmatism delay moral progress?

Tags: ethics, pragmatism, moral-realism, moral-dilemma

I read a recent paper about [trophy hunting](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10531-023-02597-9). In it, the authors have a footnote that argues against people who oppose trophy hunting on the basis that it is absolutely wrong.

The authors write:

> "these arguments are so far removed from our practical experiences of
> wildlife conservation and community development, as well as our
> pragmatic commitments to solutions that benefit people and
> biodiversity, that we do not address them here."

But this seems like a case of kicking the can down the road. My contention is that *if* trophy hunting is wrong, its pragmatic benefits should not hinder moral progress in the form of banning it outright.

Comment: It's often said, "Just because everyone is doing it, doesn't make it right." But I wonder if everyone doing something at least just makes it neutral. [~100,000 is a likelier number, but 3,000,000 people *might* have participated in the Rwandan genocide;](https://asq.africa.ufl.edu/waters_97/) would punishing all those people be a useful expenditure of resources? How do we prove that trophy hunting, or genocide, or whatever, are wrong enough to merit that kind of resource allocation?

Comment: Now, I realize I worded that unclearly; not to say that trophy hunting or genocide themselves are widely practiced so much as that many people are *allowed*, by many *more* people, to do such things. The inaction of masses in the face of these things is what I'm getting at more as neutral.